# No suitable driver with jar on application lib

Tags: mule, c3p0

on Mule ESB 3.7.0 CE
I have configured a C3P0 connection:

```
<bean id="dbConnection"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="${diap6.centraleurope.company}" />
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="${db.persistence.xml}" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
            <property name="showSql" value="${diap6.centraleurope.show_sql}" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitPostProcessors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="entitiesCompanyLoader" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">${diap6.centraleurope.url}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">t6valce</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">t6valce</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${diap6.centraleurope.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">2</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">60</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">15</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">0</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTime">360</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1 from dual</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod">30</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryDelay">1000</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect">true</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

if I put the driver class jar ojdbc6.jar on apps/myapp/lib I get this error on application startup:

```
    WARN  2015-10-16 11:26:01,691 [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->z8kfsx9ctrp0kk4mc5wl|456c58cd]-HelperThread-#0] com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@13c79966 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception:
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315) ~[?:1.8.0_60]
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:285) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:200) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1127) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1114) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:44) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1855) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
        at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696) ~[mchange-commons-java-0.2.9.jar:0.2.9]
```

if I put the jar in the mule system library: mule-standalone-3.7.0/lib/opt the driver is found and the application starts correctly.

I'd prefer to bundle the driver with the application but seems to be impossible. Have you any solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it dipends on a class loader issue. c3p0 library is on mule-standalone-3.7.0/lib/opt so, when it calls java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver the class loader check on the mule context while the driver was loaded by a different class loader at application level.
If I put the oracle driver on mule-standalone-3.7.0/lib/opt both c3p0 and oracle driver belong to the same class loader and the getDriver() method works well.